# Get every tail faster with math/logic applied in numpy 1D array - to eliminate infinity

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array in which I need each 'column' (axis=1) to be treated independently.  For each column (1D array) I need a function applied to each length tail of the 1D array, to provide an array of length N as follows.  How do I make it faster?  Perhaps by removing the for loop.  I was doing this with map/lambda/hstack until I hit a divide by zero error, which required the if/elif/else conditions to eliminate the march to infinity.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(20,5)

def get_updown_array(loc_array):
    return np.array([updown(loc_array[x:]) for x in list(range(loc_array.shape[0]))])

def updown(local_array):
    sub_length = ((local_array.shape[0]) + 1) // 2 # to get the middle value when length is uneven
    a = local_array[:sub_length].mean() # first half mean
    b = local_array[-sub_length:].mean() # second half mean
    if not a == 0:
        return ( b - a ) / abs(a)
    elif not b == 0:
        return ( b - a ) / abs(( a + b ) / 2)
    else:
        return 0

result = np.apply_along_axis(get_updown_array, 0, x)
```

It seems the if/else conditional logic eliminates the ability to apply the function across multiple values in one numpy dimension, all at the same time.

1. I looked at using vectorize, though it seems this would still require the for loop in the first function.
2. I looked at pandas.apply though it seems slower, and still requires a concatenate or
   vstack/hstack afterward?
3. Cython was considered though this still leaves the inelegant for loop clunking away.
4. I tried np.where though this still
   needs a for loop.

Is there a way to apply the math/logic to each length tail without the for loop?  What is the fastest approach? stackoverflow community.

Comment: For a function that only works on a 1d array, simple iteration on the other is usually best.  "apply's can't be faster unless they compile your code.

Comment: `np.divide` takes a `where` and `out` parameter, allowing you to avoid divide bt 0 elements

Comment: stackoverflow community rocks!  I can't wait to tell my ~80yo Mum and mathematical sDad how at 2am Sydney time in under 30 minutes hpaulj in Seattle and Seb collaborated on linear algebraic filtered calculations to improve my and hopefully many others' knowledge.. You all have my thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```py
def updown(x):
    result = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        mid = (len(x)+1)//2
        a = x[:mid].mean(axis=0)
        b = x[-mid:].mean(axis=0)
        mask_a = a != 0
        mask_b = (a == 0) & (b != 0)
        result[i, mask_a] = (b[mask_a] - a[mask_a]) / abs(a[mask_a])
        result[i, mask_b] = (b[mask_b] - a[mask_b]) / abs((a[mask_b] + b[mask_b])/2)
        x = x[1:]
    return result
```

In cases where a loop is fairly unavoidable like here, it is best to pre-allocate the result array (if the dimensions are known beforehand) and fill the values in the loop. This also has the advantage of allowing the default value of zero to be pre-filled.

There is no need for applying anything over the columns of `x` as the other operations (`mean` and arithmetic) can be easily applied to the chosen axis.

The conditional logic is achieved with masking.

You could also make use of the `out` and `where` keyword arguments of `np.divide`:

```py
def updown(x):
    result = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        mid = (len(x)+1)//2
        a = x[:mid].mean(axis=0)
        b = x[-mid:].mean(axis=0)
        np.divide(b - a, abs(a), out=result[i], where=(a != 0))
        np.divide(b - a, abs((a + b)/2), out=result[i], where=(a == 0) & (b != 0))
        x = x[1:]
    return result
```

Let's see some performance comparisons (I've wrapped your entire original code in a function called `updown_orig`)

For dimensions `(20, 5)`, we see only a factor of 2 improvement:

```py
In []: %timeit updown_orig(np.random.rand(20, 5))
1 ms ± 13.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In []: %timeit updown(np.random.rand(20, 5))
508 µs ± 10.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Let's scale both dimensions by 10 (increasing the size of `x` by a factor of 100):

```py
In []: %timeit updown_orig(np.random.rand(200, 50))                                                                 
96.4 ms ± 1.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In []: %timeit updown(np.random.rand(200, 50))                                                                      
5.84 ms ± 64 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Now the difference is a factor of about 16.5.

Comment: Thanks Seb. Since you elaborated on the @hpaulj answer using np.divide with where and out I am now looking for this to be applied across all columns without having to use np.apply_along_axis. Can this be done in a similar fashion to array wide dot notation or similar?

Comment: This function is already to be called on the whole array, not to be applied column by column. Simply do `updown(x)`.

Comment: Perhaps I shouldn't have called my solution `updown` as in your original code that was the name of a function that operated on a single partial column, whereas in my solution you operate on the whole array with it; so I can see the confusion. (By the way, I've added some performance comparisons now.)

Comment: Superb.  And the np.divide using out and where seems about 15% faster. Thanks again.